# Unable to fill formfields in a PDF using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I tried to fill my pdf using iTextsharp library.I took reference from this tutorial [fill pdf using iTextsharp](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/scottlysle/PdfGenerator_CS06162007023347AM/PdfGenerator_CS.aspx). But when I tried this example with my pdf file it showed nothing. When I read my pdf file in pdf reader it contains null.

```
   string pdfTemplate = @"c:\authform.pdf";
   // create a new PDF reader based on the PDF template document
   PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
```

In this I get null when I read my pdf template.Is there some special format in which the pdf template should be so that it can work with this example.

Comment: Do you have a pdf file named authform.pdf in your c drive?

Comment: Yes I have placed it in C drive

Comment: @rupinder18 Why would you put a file straight under the C: drive? That's bad practice. Your question is also wrong: `pdfReader` can only be `null` if an exception is thrown. You don't tell us which exception you encountered. As for the special format for forms: are you talking about forms using AcroForm technology or about the XML Forms Architecture (XFA)? I am going to vote to close your question because you aren't giving us enough info to answer it. You should start by reading tge official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

If you check the tutorial there are two examples.

one is to read fields from existing pdf.
second one is to print data to pdf.

The following is the way to print data to pdf.

```
PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, new FileStream(newFile, FileMode.Create));
AcroFields pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;

// set form pdfFormFields
// The first worksheet and W-4 form
pdfFormFields.SetField("f1_01(0)", "1");  
pdfStamper.Close();
```